# Unity - Global illumination seems no longer applied to static objects on runtime

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap, global-illumination

First of all I'm newbie with Unity, so please forgive me if the answer of this question is obvious for any experimented developer.

So, in one of my project I have this result while I run the project in the editor:
[image]

However, on runtime I get this result:
[image]

As you can see, several objects in the scene are no longer lighted. In fact, I noticed that ALL my static objects lost their illumination on runtime. I tried with Windows and WebGL as targets, same result.

As I'm hobbyist, I may provide any info about the project configuration. Better, I can provide the Git link of my project:
https://github.com/Jeanmilost/Unity/tree/master/Survival%20Demo%20Scene

This is a demo project, but in the future I'm interested to create more serious projects, and thus I need to understand why this issue happen. So if someone can point me what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful, because I already spent some hours to search the solution, without success.

Comment: Go to Edit>RenderSettings and check the ambient light see if it helps.
Then try Edit>ProjectSettings>Quality and set to high, or set light pixel count to at least 5.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue finally. I configured the quality to very low in the project settings, which ruined the lighting of my scene. Please forgive my ignorance but I'm a beginner :-)